# XSL Calculation With Node Values From Different Parent

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, xslt-1.0

I've been working on this for several hours, and I trust that you, the community, will be able to come up with the logic for the following:

**XML Nodes**

```
<Main>
 <Info>
  <Class Discipline="PHIL" Number="100" Gpa_grade_pts="3" Id_num="0030" Gpa_credits="3" >
  <Class Discipline="HIST" Number="103" Gpa_grade_pts="6" Id_num="0005" Gpa_credits="3" >
  <Class Discipline="HIST" Number="262" Gpa_grade_pts="9" Id_num="0026" Gpa_credits="3" >
 </Info>
 <Section>
  <Class Discipline="HIST" Number="103" Credits="3" Id_num="0030" Code="BAD"/>
  <Class Discipline="HIST" Number="111" Credits="3" Id_num="0005" Code="GOOD"/>
  <Class Discipline="HIST" Number="262" Credits="3" Id_num="0026" Code="BAD"
 </Section>
</Main>
```

I need to essentially loop through and find courses where /Section/Class/Code="BAD" and EXCLUDE these from the following XSL (GPA) calculation...

**XSL**

```
 <xsl:variable name="IdNum">
  <xsl:value-of select="Section/Class[@Code = 'BAD']/@Id_num" />  
 </xsl:variable>  

 <xsl:variable name="GpaGradePts">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(Info/Class[@Id_num != $IdNum]/@Gpa_grade_pts)" />
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="GpaCredits">
  <xsl:value-of select="sum(Info/Class[@Id_num != $IdNum]/@Gpa_credits)" />
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="Gpa">
  <xsl:value-of select='format-number($GpaGradePts div $GpaCredits, "#.00")' /> <!-- New GPA -->
 </xsl:variable>

 <!-- Display the new value -->

 <xsl:value-of select="$Gpa" />
```

Summary:

I need to compare the Id_num nodes from each respective portion of the XML, determine which Codes are "BAD".. and then exclude those courses from the GPA calculation. My logic only works if there is a single /Section/Class[@CODE='BAD']/@Id_num returned, thus I need to find a way for all "BAD" courses to be != (not included) in the calculation.

Using xsl version 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `<xsl:value-of>` to define the variable values they will all be strings, so it is better to use the select attribute in `xsl:variable` directly.

You can start collecting the ids of the BAD courses (if `MAIN` is the context node) as you already did:

```
<xsl:variable name="BadIdNums" select="Section/Class[@Code = 'BAD']/@Id_num"/>
```

Here is how to use this node-set variable as a filter for Course elements in the Info section:

```
<xsl:variable name="GpaGradePts" 
    select="sum(Info/Class[not(string(@Id_num) = $BadIdNums)]/@Gpa_grade_pts)"/>
```

To understand the filter [remember](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans) that

> If one object to be compared is a node-set and the other is a string,
>   then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the
>   node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the
>   string-value of the node and the other string is true.